# wp_deregister_style with md5 variable?

Tags: wp-register-style

I want to deregister Google Fonts to defer the loading. The style id is dynamic.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-google-fonts-' . md5( $google_font_url ), $google_font_url, array() );
```

How can I deregister or dequeue a function like that?

Thanks!!

Comment: the same way ? :) `wp_deregister_style('theme-google-fonts-' . md5( $google_font_url ));`

Comment: Thanks, Laxmana!

I did try that, but it's not working for me... how can I find out what wp hook the wp_enqueue_style function is executing in? I can't figure out if it's init, wp_head, wp_enqueue_scripts, wp_print_styles. 

None work for me.

Comment: Normally a `wp_enqueue_style` should be executing in `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. `admin_enqueue_scripts` for enqueuing on admin pages and `login_enqueue_scripts` for enqueuing on the login page. So `wp_deregister_style` should run also in `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook